# MIUI 14 with Android 13, app second run always crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-13

I recently updated my Xiaomi 12X to MIUI 14 Android 13 (xiaomi.eu XM12X V14.0.8.0 TLDCNXM). And I had a problem, it's impossible to run the application from Android Studio a second time, it crashes right away. I've tried it on other devices and it works fine. I also tried to create a new project, the first launch was successful, but if you run it again without changing anything, the application no longer starts. And nothing is showing up in Logcat

Here is Error Logcat

```
2023-03-02 11:03:28.614 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
2023-03-02 11:03:28.614 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices no uidString 
2023-03-02 11:03:28.615 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices no uidString 
2023-03-02 11:03:28.615 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices contains uidString : 10109
2023-03-02 11:03:28.615 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices contains uidString : 10109
2023-03-02 11:03:28.615 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
2023-03-02 11:03:28.615 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
2023-03-02 11:03:28.616 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.nearby.mediums.nearfieldcommunication.NfcAdvertisingService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.616 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.xiaomi.digitalkey/com.xiaomi.digitalkey.ccc.OnHostService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.616 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.pay.hce.service.PayHceService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.616 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.dck.service.DckNfcApduService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.622 6433-6433/? E/libnfc_nci: [ERROR:SecureElement.cpp(1470)] SecureElement::getEeInfo: num EEs discovered: 2
2023-03-02 11:03:28.639 25874-25874/? E/studio.deploy: Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2023-03-02 11:03:28.811 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices no uidString 
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices no uidString 
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices contains uidString : 10109
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: installedServices contains uidString : 10109
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
2023-03-02 11:03:28.812 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
2023-03-02 11:03:28.813 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.nearby.mediums.nearfieldcommunication.NfcAdvertisingService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.813 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.xiaomi.digitalkey/com.xiaomi.digitalkey.ccc.OnHostService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.813 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.pay.hce.service.PayHceService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.813 6433-6433/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: component namecom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.dck.service.DckNfcApduService
2023-03-02 11:03:28.819 6433-6433/? E/libnfc_nci: [ERROR:SecureElement.cpp(1470)] SecureElement::getEeInfo: num EEs discovered: 2
2023-03-02 11:03:28.819 6433-6433/? E/libnfc_nci: [ERROR:SecureElement.cpp(1470)] SecureElement::getEeInfo: num EEs discovered: 2
2023-03-02 11:03:28.864 1170-1236/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-03-02 11:03:28.864 1170-1236/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-03-02 11:03:28.864 1999-7180/? E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
2023-03-02 11:03:28.897 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: get all recent tasks force including 39
2023-03-02 11:03:28.901 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: size=2
2023-03-02 11:03:28.901 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=39   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=268435456 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.example.murodildoyober13/com.example.murodildoyober13.MainActivity} }
2023-03-02 11:03:28.901 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=28   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flag=335544320 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MiuiSettings} }
2023-03-02 11:03:28.906 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: get all recent tasks force including 39
2023-03-02 11:03:28.908 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: size=2
2023-03-02 11:03:28.908 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=39   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flag=268435456 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.example.murodildoyober13/com.example.murodildoyober13.MainActivity} }
2023-03-02 11:03:28.908 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=28   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flag=335544320 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MiuiSettings} }
2023-03-02 11:03:28.944 1170-1236/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
2023-03-02 11:03:28.982 7447-9639/? E/AppPredict: click app not fount, pkgName is com.example.murodildoyober13
2023-03-02 11:03:28.987 7447-18470/? E/AppPredict: insert result = 68
2023-03-02 11:03:29.007 7447-18233/? E/AppPredict: get screen_paper_mode_enabled fail
    android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: screen_paper_mode_enabled
        at android.provider.Settings.parseIntSetting(Unknown Source:16)
        at android.provider.Settings.-$$Nest$smparseIntSetting(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.getIntForUser(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.miui.apppredict.f.h.a(Unknown Source:553)
        at com.miui.apppredict.c.b.c(Unknown Source:82)
        at com.miui.apppredict.service.AppPredictService.b(Unknown Source:40)
        at com.miui.apppredict.service.AppPredictService.e(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.miui.apppredict.service.AppPredictService$d.handleMessage(Unknown Source:60)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:19)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(Unknown Source:28)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.008 7447-18254/? E/AppPredictBayes: write to file
2023-03-02 11:03:29.008 7447-18255/? E/AppPredictBayesNew: write to file
2023-03-02 11:03:29.128 26106-26106/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x26cff465000010 in tid 26106 (re-initialized>), pid 26106 (re-initialized>)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/psyche/psyche:13/RKQ1.211001.001/V14.0.8.0.TLDCNXM:user/release-keys'
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2023-03-02 11:03:29.166948270+0500
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: Process uptime: 1s
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: <pre-initialized>
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: pid: 26106, tid: 26106, name: re-initialized>  >>> <pre-initialized> <<<
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10231
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0026cff465000010
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x0  00000075a6333cf0  x1  b4000075a67861e0  x2  0000007641bd7028  x3  0000000000000002
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x4  00000075a5fc2477  x5  0000007ffcd7f3b0  x6  6f6e207972746e45  x7  646e756f6620746f
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x8  b4000075a66add40  x9  b4000075a661cf00  x10 0000000000000005  x11 0000000000000018
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x12 b4000075a661dd40  x13 000000000461c4d8  x14 000000000461c4b8  x15 0000007636039942
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007636115a88  x17 000000763610415c  x18 0000007640e78000  x19 0000007ffcd7fa40
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007ffcd7fa40  x21 0026cff465000000  x22 000000000000001f  x23 b4000075a67861e0
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000020  x25 00000076407bc000  x26 0000007524863b1c  x27 000000005c000000
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     x28 00000076407bc000  x29 0000007ffcd7f870
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:     lr  00000075248acce4  sp  0000007ffcd7f810  pc  00000075248acdbc  pst 0000000060001000
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:   NOTE: Function names and BuildId information is missing for some frames due
      NOTE: to unreadable libraries. For unwinds of apps, only shared libraries
      NOTE: found under the lib/ directory are readable.
      NOTE: On this device, run setenforce 0 to make the libraries readable.
      NOTE: Unreadable libraries:
      NOTE:   /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000006adbc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::ArtClassDefinition::Init(art::DexFile const&)+508) (BuildId: a9c13c5eda5b2a79390d3fa1594a00dc)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000006a6c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::ArtClassDefinition::Init(art::Thread*, _jclass*)+828) (BuildId: a9c13c5eda5b2a79390d3fa1594a00dc)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000000e1b34  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libopenjdkjvmti.so (openjdkjvmti::Transformer::RetransformClasses(_jvmtiEnv*, int, _jclass* const*)+732) (BuildId: a9c13c5eda5b2a79390d3fa1594a00dc)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 000000000005a708  /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000000000005a230  /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 000000000005b9d8  /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000000510b4  /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 0000000000051bec  /data/data/com.example.murodildoyober13/code_cache/startup_agents/09f4021c-agent.so
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 0000000000687aa4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ti::AgentSpec::DoLoadHelper(_JNIEnv*, bool, _jobject*, int*, art::ti::LoadError*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+660) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 0000000000688130  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ti::AgentSpec::Attach(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int*, art::ti::LoadError*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+124) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 000000000062f1d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::AttachAgent(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*)+160) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 0000000000571c04  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::VMDebug_nativeAttachAgent(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*)+804) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000000000010cebc  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+140)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 0000000000209398  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+152) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 0000000000d57de6  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (dalvik.system.VMDebug.attachAgent+0)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 00000000010318ee  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.attemptAttachAgent+0)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 00000000010340d8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.handleAttachAgent+18)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 00000000010341aa  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.handleAttachStartupAgents+180)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 00000000010306ea  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+278)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 0000000001abe030  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+38)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 0000000001adbb18  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+364)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 0000000001adb988  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+164)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 0000000000209334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 0000000001037a12  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+246)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 0000000000210c00  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+576) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 000000000027b4ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+240) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 0000000000616f84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1400) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #34 pc 0000000000596aa0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #35 pc 000000000010b148  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+120)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #36 pc 000000000020a2b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+4016) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #37 pc 00000000023b01f0  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #38 pc 000000000020b074  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #39 pc 00000000023b63f8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.vdex (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+624)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 0000000000210c00  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+576) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #41 pc 000000000027b4ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+240) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #42 pc 000000000061770c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+452) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #43 pc 0000000000617bf8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+96) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #44 pc 00000000004ff01c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+600) (BuildId: a00788ed2b92f0a954148d2876b28e1d)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #45 pc 00000000000c0c04  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: b503f66b59ffcb029d3fd4a2f048f5eb)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #46 pc 00000000000cd80c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+924) (BuildId: b503f66b59ffcb029d3fd4a2f048f5eb)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #47 pc 0000000000002610  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1464) (BuildId: 6363373b68588b10c93602a28a32bb57)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.323 26136-26136/? A/DEBUG:       #48 pc 00000000000858d4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100) (BuildId: c952e6203717f15ddb4a9646718f3c46)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.334 26136-26136/? E/MIUINDBG: miui_native_debug_process_O
2023-03-02 11:03:29.334 26136-26136/? E/MIUINDBG: unable to connect to mqsas native socket
2023-03-02 11:03:29.334 750-750/? E/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: tombstone_06
2023-03-02 11:03:29.362 1999-4910/? E/ProcessManager: error write exception log
2023-03-02 11:03:29.372 18003-18003/? E/RotationHelper: setCurrentTransitionRequest: request=0
2023-03-02 11:03:29.383 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: get all recent tasks force including 7
2023-03-02 11:03:29.388 8137-8263/? E/PowerKeeper.Location: setUidState
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing ILocationPolicyManager
        at android.location.LocationPolicyManager.<init>(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistryImpl$3.createService(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistryImpl$3.createService(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$CachedServiceFetcher.getService(Unknown Source:43)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry.getSystemService(Unknown Source:43)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(Unknown Source:98)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.location.LocationPolicyManager.from(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.LocationController.setUidState(Unknown Source:70)
        at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.LocationController.updateRuleForUidLocked(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.LocationController.access$000(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.LocationController$1.onAppRuleChange(Unknown Source:34)
        at com.miui.powerkeeper.appcontrol.HideModeStateMachine$12.run(Unknown Source:10)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(Unknown Source:28)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.388 7447-10052/? E/AppPredict: MNNImpl::onForceChange::pkg = com.miui.home, ignore
2023-03-02 11:03:29.388 7447-10052/? E/AppPredictBayes: BayesImpl::onForceChange::pkg = com.miui.home, ignore
2023-03-02 11:03:29.388 7447-10052/? E/AppPredictBayesNew: BayesNewImpl::onForceChange::pkg = com.miui.home, ignore
2023-03-02 11:03:29.392 7447-18470/? E/AppPredict: insert result = 69
2023-03-02 11:03:29.392 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: size=1
2023-03-02 11:03:29.392 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=28   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flag=335544320 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MiuiSettings} }
2023-03-02 11:03:29.393 18003-18003/? E/Launcher.Boost: boost failed
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setThreadPriority(IILjava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/os/MiuiProcess; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.MiuiProcess' appears in /system_ext/framework/miui-framework.jar)
        at com.miui.launcher.utils.BoostHelper.boost(Unknown Source:122)
        at com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher.showPresent(Unknown Source:55)
        at com.miui.home.launcher.common.UnlockAnimationStateMachine.showAnimation(Unknown Source:70)
        at com.miui.home.launcher.common.UnlockAnimationStateMachine.onResume(Unknown Source:56)
        at com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher.onResume(Unknown Source:213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Unknown Source:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(Unknown Source:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(Unknown Source:32)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(Unknown Source:79)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:19)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:312)
2023-03-02 11:03:29.394 18003-18003/? E/BranchAllAppsIndicator: changedByBranch: callBack = null
2023-03-02 11:03:29.395 18003-18003/? E/RotationHelper: setCurrentTransitionRequest: request=0
2023-03-02 11:03:29.398 1999-2764/? E/MiuiActivityController: MiuiLog-ActivityObserver: There was something wrong : null
2023-03-02 11:03:29.410 26150-26150/? E/gle.android.gms: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-03-02 11:03:29.417 1999-2764/? E/MiuiActivityController: MiuiLog-ActivityObserver: There was something wrong : null
2023-03-02 11:03:29.419 1999-2764/? E/MiuiActivityController: MiuiLog-ActivityObserver: There was something wrong : null
2023-03-02 11:03:29.501 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: get all recent tasks force including 7
2023-03-02 11:03:29.504 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: size=1
2023-03-02 11:03:29.504 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=28   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flag=335544320 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MiuiSettings} }
2023-03-02 11:03:29.509 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: get all recent tasks force including 7
2023-03-02 11:03:29.510 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: size=1
2023-03-02 11:03:29.510 18003-18200/? E/ActivityManagerWrapper: getRecentTasks: mainTaskId=28   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flag=335544320 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.MiuiSettings} }
2023-03-02 11:03:29.597 18003-18369/? E/Launcher.Transfer: transfer is closed
2023-03-02 11:03:29.904 1170-6716/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: VmRssMeter:: start() 447: Could not find pid, can not collect vmrss data
2023-03-02 11:03:29.904 1170-6717/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: VmRssMeter:: start() 447: Could not find pid, can not collect vmrss data
2023-03-02 11:03:29.905 1170-6717/? E/ANDR-PERF-LM: AdaptiveLaunch: writeToDataBase() 64: Meter aborted or could not get meter data for this run
2023-03-02 11:03:30.873 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: failed for /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu0-llcc-ddr-lat/min_freq as previous value is not stored
2023-03-02 11:03:30.873 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: failed for /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable as previous value is not stored
2023-03-02 11:03:30.874 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: failed for /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu-cpu-llcc-bw/min_freq as previous value is not stored
2023-03-02 11:03:30.874 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: failed for /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu-cpu-llcc-bw/max_freq as previous value is not stored
2023-03-02 11:03:30.945 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-UTIL: Failed to update node /proc/26106/sched_boost with value 0
2023-03-02 11:03:30.946 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: can't reset task 26106
2023-03-02 11:03:30.946 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to reset optimization [3, 32]
2023-03-02 11:03:32.395 18003-18003/? E/Launcher.Boost: boost failed
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setThreadPriority(IILjava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/os/MiuiProcess; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.MiuiProcess' appears in /system_ext/framework/miui-framework.jar)
        at com.miui.launcher.utils.BoostHelper.boost(Unknown Source:142)
        at com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher$65.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:312)
2023-03-02 11:03:32.398 1170-1235/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: failed for /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/min_pwrlevel as previous value is not stored
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xRJ9pPYQks

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you got a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable "**Always install with package manager**" option in run configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx8zg.png

Comment: Thank you. I have already received an answer on the Xiaomi.eu forum. Forgot to add solution here

Comment: The picture cannot be opened anymore